# Verificacion de tipos en Java

Tags: java

Necesito saber si Java tiene algún constructor que no pueda hacer verificación de tipo de dato de forma estática y que es lo que hace, si hace la verificación de forma dinámica o deja la construcción sin verificación durante la ejecución.

Comment: No queda nada claro (para mí al menos) lo que preguntas. Puedes explicar en más detalle (tal vez con un ejemplo) a qué verificación te refieres?

Comment: Me refiero a verificacion de tipos de datos.. Java hace la verificacion de manera estatica(en tiempo de compilacion). Y quiero saber si tiene algun constructor que no pueda hacer esa verificacion y queda para etapas posteriores

Comment: ¿Con constructor a etapas posteriores te refieres a algún constructor de la forma `new ClaseX` que la instancia devuelta no sea de tipo `ClaseX` sino de tipo `ClaseY`, por poner un ejemplo?

Answer (score 3):

La verificación de tipos se realiza en tiempo de compilación, luego se generan los bytecodes que son interpretados por la máquina virtual de Java (JVM). Existe una instrucción de la JVM que podría acercarse al comportamiento que preguntas, la cual es `invokedynamic`. En este [blog](http://blog.headius.com/2008/09/first-taste-of-invokedynamic.html) hay una explicación muy detallada y extensa.

Comment: El artículo data del 2008. Esta información creo que es muy antigua

Answer (score 2):

El compilador, una vez ha validado el código Java, lo convierte a bytecode y elimina la información que tenía sobre el tipo de dato de los objetos ([**type erasure**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_erasure)). En tiempo de ejecución no se dispone de la información suficiente para saber de qué tipo era un objeto, por lo que es frecuente que ciertas operaciones de *casting* se hagan a ciegas y con bastante posibilidad de que fallen:

```
String[] strings = new String[10];

Object[] objects = strings;

objects[0] = new Object(); //<-- java.lang.ArrayStoreException
```

Creo que esto contesta a la última pregunta: los tipos de datos no se pueden verificar dinámicamente en tiempo de ejecución. En cuanto a si hay algún constructor cuyo tipo no se pueda verificar en tiempo de compilación, supongo que te refieres a algún tipo genérico. Java no cuenta con inferencia de tipos como otros lenguajes, por lo que todo tiene que tener definido su tipo en tiempo de compilación, incluso las expresiones lambda en java8 que dan la impresión de no usar tipos.

Otra cosa a considerar sería la **seguridad de tipos** (*type safety*). Aunque el compilador valide tipos, es muy posible que tampoco cuente con toda la información para *asegurar* que el tipo de una operación sea el correcto. Desde las propias implementaciones se deben reforzar esta seguridad impidiendo *operaciones externas*. Por ejemplo, la clase `BigDecimal` no permite operaciones que den resultados no representables por ella misma:

```
BigDecimal a = new BigDecimal(3);
BigDecimal b = BigDecimal.ONE.divide(a); // <- java.lang.ArithmeticException
```

Lo ideal hubiera sido que el compilador tuviera la información necesaria para validar el tipo resultante de estos cálculos. Esto es lo que se intenta hacer en scala con su nuevo compilador, [dotty](https://github.com/lampepfl/dotty), que puede hacer comprobaciones complejas de tipos a partir de un lenguaje de definición de tipos llamado DOT (*Dependent Object Types*).

---

**Editado**: a partir del comentario de @Luiggi-Mendoza, voy a poner un código similar, pero específico de *type-erasure*, sin usar *arrays*:

```java
Vector<String> strings = new Vector<String>(10);

Vector objects = strings;

objects.add(new Object());

Object anObject = strings.get(0);

String aString = strings.get(0);
```

Este código *"compila"*, dando error en tiempo de ejecución en la última línea. Explicado línea a línea:

Creación de un vector de `Strings`:

```
Vector<String> strings = new Vector<String>(10);
```

*casting* a vector genérico:

```
Vector objects = strings;
```

Como `objects` es un vector genérico, no da error al añadir un objeto:

```
objects.add(new Object());
```

Al extraer un elemento del vector, no se produce error de conversión porque el compilador ha eliminado toda conversión implícita a `String` por eficiencia:

```
Object anObject = strings.get(0);
```

Por contra, si queremos convertirlo a `String` dará error porque ha perdido información del tipo genérico inicial que tenía el `Vector<String>`:

```
String aString = strings.get(0); // <-- java.lang.ClassCastException:
                        // java.lang.Object cannot be cast to java.lang.String
```

Comment: En el primer párrafo se mezclan varias cosas. Primero que nada, Java es un lenguaje de tipado estático, sí se conocen los tipos de los datos con antelación, por ende el compilador lanza errores cuando no puede determinar si se está usando el tipo de dato correcto. En tiempo de ejecución, todas las operaciones que hacen uso de genéricos sufren del borrado de tipo (type erasure), pero esto **no aplica a los arreglos** como lo haces en ese ejemplo. Ese caso de los arreglos es un problema mayor en el diseño de Java de covarencia en los objetos y no en los genéricos.

Comment: Tienes razón. Luiggi. Voy a ver si lo puedo hacer mejor.